# Calculating change in percentage between two numbers (Python)

Tags: python

I have a list of prices where I am trying to calculate the change in percentage of each number. I calculated the differences with

```
    prices = [30.4, 32.5, 31.7, 31.2, 32.7, 34.1, 35.8, 37.8, 36.3, 36.3, 35.6]

    def f():
        for i in range(len(prices)):
            print(prices[i]-prices[i-1])
```

Which returns the differences like

```
    2.1
    -0.8
    -0.5
    ...
```

I know the change in percentage would be ((i-(i-1))/(i-1) *100, but I don't know how to incorporate that into the script. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You probably want `range(1, len(prices))`- otherwise the first thing it prints will be the difference between the last and first elements of the list.

Comment: You have the change percentage equation wrong... You may be thinking of a % error equation which goes like abs(x-y)/x, where x is the correct value in theory, but difference is abs(x-y) / average x, y

Comment: You're right, David. I changed the range as you suggested and amended the last line to `print ((prices[i]-prices[i-1])/prices[i-1]*100)`

Comment: It's a bit late to ask, but how could I convert the output of f() into a list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
prices = [30.4, 32.5, 31.7, 31.2, 32.7, 34.1, 35.8, 37.8, 36.3, 36.3, 35.6]

for a, b in zip(prices[::1], prices[1::1]):
    print 100 * (b - a) / a
```

**Edit:** If you want this as a list, you could do this:

```
print [100 * (b - a) / a for a, b in zip(prices[::1], prices[1::1])]
```

Comment: Edit: After the first couple of values, the numbers go off: 6.90789473684 ,-1.57728706625 ,4.28134556575
, 5.58659217877
, 0.0
, 0.0
, 0.0
, 0.0
, -5.5900621118
, 0.327868852459
, 0.0

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: Maybe I copied you code wrong, I don't know. I have the correct output here: 6.90789473684,
 -2.46153846154
, -1.57728706625
, 4.80769230769
, 4.28134556575
, 4.9853372434
, 5.58659217877
, -3.96825396825
, 0.0
, -1.92837465565
, 0.0. However, do you know how I could convert all those individual outputs into a single list?

Comment: That is exactly what this outputs, except for the last 0.0 -- but shouldn't there be only 10 outputs (not 11)??

Comment: Hm. You're right. I must've entered it wrong. My actual prices list is longer than what I entered here, so I guess I entered a different list when giving you those numbers. I'd like the output to be like ['6.90789473684', '-2.46153846154' , '-1.57728706625' , '4.80769230769'...] instead of individually though.

Answer (score 23):

If you haven't been exposed to the pandas library in Python (http://pandas.pydata.org/), you should definitely check it out.

Doing this is as easy as:

```
import pandas as pd
prices = [30.4, 32.5, 31.7, 31.2, 32.7, 34.1, 35.8, 37.8, 36.3, 36.3, 35.6]

price_series = pd.Series(prices)
price_series.pct_change()
```

Answer (score 2):

Though definitely not the most elegant way, if you'd like to define a function it would look something like this:

```
def pctc(Q):
    output = [0]
    for i in range(len(Q)):
        if i > 0:
            increase = Q[i]-Q[i-1]
            percentage = (increase/Q[i]) * 100
            output.append(percentage)
    return(output)
```

There's probably even a better way to do that function, but it's clear at least. :))