# Using list index values to compute list value changes in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists for years and unemployment rates:

```
datalist= [[1947, 3.9], [1948, 3.8], [1949, 5.9], [1950, 5.3], [1951, 3.3], 
           [1952, 3.0], [1953, 2.9], [1954, 5.5], [1955, 4.4] . . .]
```

I am able to modify the year (adding 1 to it) via

```
def newYear(a):
    newList = datalist[:]
    for i in range(len(newList)):
        newList[i][0] += 1
    return newList
```

I'm looking to create a new list of lists with the year and percent change in the unemployment rate from the previous year. I tried adding
b, a and c to the function, but I don't know how to make this work.

```
def newYear(a):
    newList = datalist[:]
    for i in range(len(newList)):
        newList[i][0] += 1

        b = newList[i + 1][1]
        a = newList[i][1]
        c = (b-a)/a * 100

    return newList
```

Comment: I suggest using a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: Related: [Calculating change in percentage between two numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12700166/176646)

Comment: When the rate changes from 5 to 8, do you expect a change of 3% or 60% ?

Comment: @fafl I interpreted as 60%, it looks like that's what the current approach with indices is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to stick as close as possible to your current approach, you can try this. Looking forwards (i.e. using `x+1` indexing) makes things more difficult for you; the first year in your list cannot have a percentage change from the previous year. You would also get an `IndexError` by using `range(len(a))` when you got to the last item in your list. So it's more natural to use `x` and then look one period backwards (`x-1`).

```
datalist= [[1947, 3.9], [1948, 3.8], [1949, 5.9], [1950, 5.3], [1951, 3.3], 
           [1952, 3.0], [1953, 2.9], [1954, 5.5], [1955, 4.4]]

def newYear(a):
    new_list = []
    new_list.append([a[0][0], a[0][1], 0]) # No change for first year
    for x in range(1, len(a)):
        year = a[x][0]
        previous_unemployment = a[x-1][1]
        current_unemployment = a[x][1]
        percent_change = ((current_unemployment - previous_unemployment) 
                        / previous_unemployment)*100
        new_list.append([year, current_unemployment, percent_change])

    return new_list

calc_percentages = newYear(datalist)
print calc_percentages
```